# Fast algorithm to compute the length of a Farey sequence

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, math

### The problem

I'm trying to solve [this CodinGame puzzle](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/heart-of-the-city):

> #### Heart of the City
>
> Consider an imaginary city which is an `n` × `n` square cells where a building is located at center of each cell (except the central cell), so in total there are `n` * `n` - 1 buildings. The buildings in this city are all circular and very very small width-wise. All the buildings in the city are the same.
>
> One day you decided to take a walk in this city and go to its center. From that spot you could see many other buildings, but not all of them, because the buildings in the same directions block each other. How many of these buildings could you see in this city?

I need to take one input, `n` (1 < `n` < 10000000, `n` % 2 = 1), and output the number of visible buildings.

For example, for `n` = 7, I need to output 32 as the result (`@` represents the center, ***`#`*** a visible building (or Pisa tower?) and `_` a non-visible one):

```
_ # # _ # # _
# _ # _ # _ #
# # # # # # #
_ _ # @ # _ _
# # # # # # #
# _ # _ # _ #
_ # # _ # # _
```

### Testcases

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 8 |
| 7 | 32 |
| 11 | 80 |
| 33 | 640 |
| 999999 | 607926717408 |
| 931547 | 527547299504 |
| 9999999 | 60792708184960 |

### What I tried

By myself I figured out that the final result will always be divisible by 8, which means I only need to compute the number of visible buildings in an eighth of the city and multiply that by 8. Let the center be (0, 0), the number of visible buildings in that eighth is equals to the number of points (`x`, `y`) where:

- 1 <= `x` < `y` < `N` = (`n` + 1) / 2, and
- `gcd(x, y)` = 1

After a while worth of googling, I found out that the name of this problem is [Farey sunburst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Farey_sunburst). The following JavaScript version of the iterative Python implementation given at that Wikipedia page runs fast enough to pass the first four testcases (`n` <= 33, `N` ), but fails at the fifth (`n` = 999,999):

```js
const f = n => {
    let s = 0;
    let [i, j, k, l] = [0n, 1n, 1n, n];

    while (k <= n) {
        let t = (n + j) / l | 0n;
        [i, j, k, l] = [k, l, t * k - i, t * l - j];
        s++;
    }

    return s;
};
```

I then found the following formula on the same page:

> |F<sub>n</sub>| = |F<sub>n-1</sub>| + phi(n)

...and implemented it as such:

```js
const gcd = (a, b) => {
    while (b) {
        [a, b] = [b, a % b];
    }
    return a;
};

const phi = n => {
    let s = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        s += gcd(n, i) === 1;
    }
    return s;
};

const f = n => {
    let s = 1;
    for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        s += phi(i);
    }
    return s;
};
```

That too didn't make its way pass testcase 5 due to its O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity. I tried reading the rest of the page, only to find myself in a [rabbit hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_rabbit_hole) as I'm not very good at math.

Thanks to @MrSmith42's comments, I got a better `phi()` from [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eulers-totient-function/), which was good enough to pass most testcases except for the last (it took ~7.6 seconds on my local machine):

```js
const phi = n => {
    let s = n;

    for (let i = 2; i ** 2 <= n; i++) {
        if (!(n % i)) {
            while (!(n % i)) {
                n = n / i | 0;
            }
            s -= s / i | 0;
        }
    }

    if (n > 1) {
        s -= s / n | 0;
    }

    return s;
};
```

Please answer in layman's term: Which algorithm do I need to solve this puzzle?

### Environment limits

According to [this information page](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/40701/help-center/languages-versions), a Linux environment on a 64-bit multi-core architecture will be running my code, and I'm limited to 768 MB of memory. A quick experiment shows that the time limit is ~6 seconds.

<sub>P/S: I have also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54513531), but the function provided by OP is also too slow for my use case.</sub>

Comment: I'd certainly appreciate it if the downvoters could explain their reasoning so that I can improve this question. I'm pretty sure that I explained the problem and my thoughts as best as I could.

Comment: Also, I don't see how this question is lacking focus as a close voter implies. I showed my (failed) attempts, didn't I?

Comment: As you can read here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eulers-totient-function/ your current implemenattion is `O(n² *log n)` not O(n²) but can be improved see pa5ragraph 'Below is a Better Solution'. That may already be enough for passing the tests.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Thanks a lot! It did help me pass most of the testcases. It's still too slow for the last (1e7 - 1) though.

Comment: @InSync Algorithm questions often get downvoted if you use a language-specific tag on the question. Since what you want is an algorithm, try removing the javascript tag, and possibly adding the math tag.

Comment: @Dave I need to emphasize that the language is important here: A slow algorithm (e.g. the third one in my question) may still pass with C/C++ but not with JS (I certainly can just switch to C/C++ but that sure defeats the purpose). The [tag:math] tag was a good suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but your calculation of the totient function is still too slow, because finding the prime factors of all those numbers takes a long time.

Let P(n) be the product of the prime factors of n.

Let Q(n) be the product of (p-1) for each prime factor p of n.

Then we can calculate the totient easily:  ϕ(n) = n * Q(n) / P(n).

In order to speed up your Farey sequence calculation, you should calculate all P(n) and Q(n) at the same time, in advance, using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Instead of using an array of Booleans, though, and just crossing off a number when you discover that it has a factor, you use two arrays for `P[n]` and `Q[n]`, with all values initially 1.  When you discover that a number `i` has a prime factor `p`, you just do `P[i]*=p; Q[i]*=(p-1);`

Using this sieve, you calculate *all* the totients you need in O(n log n) time, and that will be the complexity for your complete solution.

I fixed up the implementation that you provided in comment:

```js
const n = +readline()
const N = (n + 1) / 2;

const P = Array(N+1).fill(1);
const Q = Array(N+1).fill(1);

for (let i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
    if (P[i]===1) {
        // i is prime
        for (let j=i; j<=N; j+=i) {
            P[j]*=i;
            Q[j]*=(i-1);
        }
    }
}

const phi = n => (n / P[n]) * Q[n];

const f = n => {
    let s = 1;
    for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        s += phi(i);
    }
    return s;
};
console.log(f(N) * 8);
```

Comment: This algorithm seems to be the one I was looking for; it's blazingly fast. There's a minor problem though: [I'm not implementing it correctly](https://gist.github.com/InSyncWithFoo/abb72dc31201572b913122e9372e9a8d). Sorry for being an idiot but... could you have a look?

Comment: Sure.  I added a fixed version to the answer.